# VIP Access Validation

Tags: validation

I use VIP access (installed in my mobile) that generates a random token number, which will be used to login to another Machine.

Today my mobile was not connected to the internet but I was still able to login to another machine using the token getting displayed in my mobile VIP access.

I am curious to understand How the random VIP access code is validated while logging in even when my mobile is not connected to internet?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to know how 2FA apps (like Google Authenticator or similar) could work. As you surely know, the mobile can generate a token that can be used and it works even if the generator device is offline and after some time, the token expires and a new token is generated.

To do this, there is an important requirement: The system time on the generator device and the server (you use for loving in) must be the same. It is no problem if it is off by e.g. one millisecond but the token would be generated and displayed at the wrong time.

The key of making this is encryption. You could do it the following way:

- You tell the login server that you trust this phone.
- The key server creates a key and sends out to the key generator(the mobile phone).
- Every minute (it could be another time but this needs to be specified), your phone encrypts the time using the key.
- When logging in, the server calculates the last time a key is generated and generates a key.
- The server compared the keys.

You may get better security using asymmetric encryption:

- The key generator (phone) creates a key pair and sends out the public key login server.
- You tell the login server that you trust this phone and the key server accepts the key from the phone.
- Every minute (it could be another time but this needs to be specified), your phone signs/encryptd the time using it's private key (that results in the 2fa token).
- When logging in, the server decrypts the phones token(that you entered) using the public key.
- The server tests if the decrypted token matches the time and grants you access (or not).

#### Notes:

the 2FA token is only 6 digits or something like that. This is not a complete timestamp. This could be achieved by using the time before encrypting it and takes e.g. the first 6 digits. The server (that knows the expected key) decrypts the token and does the same thing and compares those abbrieviated hashes.

I think that it could also improve the security of the phone initially sends it's machine key to the login server with it's public key so that both parties use this for hashing.

The initial handshake (where the key is exchanged) must be using a secure connection.

I have not looked into 2FA, this is just an idea how that can be done.